# Create missing data on RowSelected

Tags: acumatica

We have a graph extension that manages the tab we added to a screen. The tab displays data from our own DAC. We do not use a DAC extension, not going to go into the reasons right now.

When a user opens the main screen I want to create a record of our data if it does not exist, with some defaulting business logic.

I added a `RowSelected` event handler on the main DAC and it fires as I expect it to. When I add the code to create our missing record in the event handler Acuminator gives me error "PX1044 Changes to PXCache cannot be performed in event handlers."

I understand the error that Acuminator is raising, but I'm not sure where else to create our record. I cannot remember a section of the university specifically addressing this scenario.

Can anyone tell me how I would handle this scenario? And if possible, point me at the learning material that covers this scenario for broader information.

Comment: Adding "missing data" when you view a record sounds like you are trying to populate as records are hit instead of backfilling data.  If this is the case, you should consider just backfilling the data.  If you don't want to do it in a DB script, you could use import scenarios or write an action to click manually to execute your code.  Of course, that assumes you HAVE to store it in the database.  You could populate the values in a RowSelecting or Field Selecting event, but saving to the database is done in Persist.  So you could backfill initially and put your code in an override of Persist.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @BrianStevens. I guess you can say I am 'lazy back filling' :) I would prefer to only create the record if and when the user uses the graph

Comment: If you don’t need user input to decide the data and don’t actually need the data in the database because business logic knows what it is, you can use unbound fields and populate on fieldselecting or rowselecting.  That is how I would do it.  If it was important data for reports or other business logic, it would be important to backfill completely.

Comment: Thanks @BrianStevens, we only default the values with business logic, then we save whatever changes a user may make. I'll consider the back filling idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a reply from Acumatica support, you can do this in a view select delegate.

Here's some example code, I haven't tested it though:

```
public class InventoryItemMaintExtension : PXGraphExtension<InventoryItemMaint>
{
    public SelectFrom<MyCustomTable>.
              Where<MyCustomTable.inventoryID.IsEqual<
              InventoryItem.inventoryID.FromCurrent>>.
              View AdditionalItemData;
    public static bool IsActive() { return true; }

    public IEnumerable additionalItemData()
    {
        var data = AdditionalItemData.SelectSingle();
        if (data is null)
        {
            data = new MyCustomTable();
            AdditionalItemData.Insert(data);
        }

        return AdditionalItemData.Select();
    }
}

[PXCacheName("Additional Item Data")]
[Serializable]
public class MyCustomTable : IBqlTable
{
    #region CashAccountID
    [Inventory]
    [PXDefault]
    public virtual int? InventoryID { get; set; }
    public abstract class inventoryID : PX.Data.BQL.BqlInt.Field<inventoryID> { }

    #endregion

    #region Required
    [PXDBBool()]
    [PXDefault(false)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Required")]
    public virtual bool? Required { get; set; }
    public abstract class required : PX.Data.BQL.BqlBool.Field<required> { }
    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatly there are only a few OK ways to do this and make Acuminator happy. You will risk data inconsistency.

https://github.com/Acumatica/Acuminator/blob/master/docs/diagnostics/PX1044.md

I would reccomend putting your data insertion code in Row Updated and hope the user updates something

Comment: Thanks Kyle. How would I go about creating a new instance of the DAC to bind fields to? The RowUpdated event will fire too late in the process.

Comment: If you want to insert data, you can do:
var dac = new Dac()
{
    Field1 = someValue
};
Base.View.Insert(dac);
Bsae.Actions.PressSave()

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm doing, but I'm doing it in The RowSelected event, which is not recommended practice, I need to know where else I can do it

Comment: There is nowhere reccomended to do it except for in the RowInserted and RowUpdated and RowDeleted event